# Aligning jumbotron image in the same 12 column grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started learning HTML and CSS a week ago, and have been learning using coursera and codeacademy. I wanted to make a simple website using bootstrap, with a navigation bar on top, and a big cover pic below that.

The code looks as follows.

```
<body>
    <header class="container">
        <div class="logo"> <!--this is where the logo resides-->
            <div class="row">  <!--making a row for header elements-->

                <figure class="col-xs-7">
                    <a href="/"> </a> 
                </figure>

                <div class="col-xs-5" > <!--adds the 3 buttons on top right-->
                    <button type="button">
                        <em class="cogs"> </em>
                    </button>

                    <button type="button">
                        <em class="cogs"> </em>
                    </button>

                    <button type="button">
                        <em class="cogs"> </em>
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                

        </div>

    </header>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
            <figure class="col-xs-12"> </figure> <!--cover pic-->

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open the html in the browser (with the style sheet), I get the image attached. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od3bW.png). I though the cover pic would automatically align within the 12 column grid below the navigation bar on top, cropping out the sides. My questions are:
1. Doesn't adding an image automatically fit it in the 12 grid system?
2. How do I push the 3 icons on top to the right of the navigation bar (i.e to the right of the column)?

Thanks a ton guys! I'm grateful for any advise or suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think the jumbotron class is formatted purposely to reach the edges of the page.

If I am understanding your question correctly in that you *do not* want the jumbotron to extend to the edge of the screen, you may want to Place the jumbotron inside the div class="container" as [W3CSchools suggests](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_jumbotron&stacked=h)

2. Bootstrap v3 is neat because it has already created [tools like the nav bar](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp). You could try using an using the "< nav >" tag and an unordered list like so:

   ```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
       <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <!--- image of your logo -->
         </a>         
       </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
        </ul>
     </div>
   </nav>
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert! It worked perfect! I decided to keep the jumotron as it looked nice, but have made the icons align with the navbar.